# My asp.net data grid won't reading from xml file

Tags: asp.net, xml, sharepoint

This is my first time using asp.net so pleaseaccept my apologies if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to make a web application that will work on our work sharepoint.  the idea is a team of people can select when they are available to call or not and if they are the contact point that day so that people on different floors can see their availability without a line of sight.

i would normally make a basic php script but sharepoint doesnt like php and we cannot reference to external resources on our network.

The issue i have is the table that should be pulling data from the xml is just a blank page... originally it gave an error saying it couldnt find that data field and i realised i needed to use xpath to be more specific... it now doesnt give any error, like its finding the field but doesnt draw it. the code is below:

```
XML database:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CRM>
  <agent>
    <id>user1</id>
    <name>name</name>
    <turret>extension</turret>
    <email>email</email>
    <status>XXXXX</status>
    <contact>N/A</contact>
  </agent>
  <agent>
    <id>user2</id>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <turret>extension</turret>
    <email>email</email>
    <status>XXXXX</status>
    <contact>N/A</contact>
  </agent>
  <agent>
    <id>user3</id>
    <name>Name 3</name>
    <turret>Extension Number</turret>
    <email>email address</email>
    <status>XXXXX</status>
    <contact>N/A</contact>
  </agent>
</CRM>
```

and the datagrid that should be pulling that data is here:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="CSTvisibility.aspx.vb" Inherits="CRM_availabilty.CSTvisibility" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:XmlDataSource ID="data" runat="server" DataFile="~/crmdata.xml" XPath="/agent"></asp:XmlDataSource> 
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Ridge" DataSourceID="data">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="CRM Agent" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="turret" HeaderText="Turret" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Available" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="contact" HeaderText="Contact Point" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `TemplateField` instead of `BoundField`. Then you have access to the `XPath`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="data">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CRM Agent">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# XPath("name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Turret">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# XPath("turret") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="mailto:<%# XPath("email") %>"><%# XPath("email") %></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The XPath in the XmlDataSource must be `XPath="CRM/agent"`